# What are the pro's and con's of writing an API test automation framework at code level as opposed to using a tool

Tags: c#, test-automation-framework, api-testing, soapui, postman

As I look into writing automation frameworks at the API layer(relatively new to this area), a question that keeps cropping up in my mind is.....why should I write an automation framework at code level in C#(with RestSharp) or Java(RestAssured), as opposed to using a tool like Postman or SoapUI and utilising what they have to create a framework?

What would be the pro's and con's of each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pros of coding:**

> - You can easily integrate your test into CI process
> - You can code any assertion logic you need in your tests
> - You can utilize any library that is suitable for your chosen coding platform
> - You can flexibly manage your test data
> - You can build whatever test report you want

**Cons of coding:**

> - It requires coding skills

**Pros of tools:**

> - They doesn't require coding skills at all or requires less coding skills
> - They have user-friendly interface
> - They are intended to address some general issues of API testing (see cons) so there are a lot of people who can help you with your problems

**Cons of tools:**

> - They are intended to address some general issues of API testing so you wouldn't likely be able to introduce more or less complicated logic of your test
> - This is not trivial to integrate the tools into CI
> - Usually tools have their reporting standard that cannot be changed or you're limited in the changes
> - You either are not able to extend tool functionality or limited in the extension by the existing plugins

Comment: great answer, another con for coding is the need to "invent the wheel", especially when it comes to reporting, execution and other infrastructure things

Comment: @rsf, with coding also other open source components, can be assembled like unit testing framework, reporting frameworks at the same time with the flexibility of the customized coded solution.